# SharePoint 2013: Drop-down Issue

Tags: 2013, dropdown, choice-field, default-value

Currently we are using SharePoint 2013 version and we have a list with drop-down column .

The condition is when we select any option from the drop-down the values should show but now even if we are not selecting any option from the drop-down list the values are showing.

This is happening only for one user.

Can anyone help me here.

Comment: Is any default value set for the choice column? You can check it in column settings.

Answer (score 0):

Is any default value set for the dropdown(choice field)?

In SharePoint, while creating a choice field by default the first choice option is set as a default value for the field/column.

Either you can change the default value or you can set it to the blank value.

Follow below steps to Check the default value:

1. Go to the List in which you have this dropdown.
2. Click in **LIST** from top ribbon.
3. Select **List Settings** from the right side end of ribbon. It will open new list settings page.
4. Scroll down to **Columns** section.
5. Click on your dropdown field name.
6. Scroll down to the bottom on new page, where you can see **Default value**.
7. You can remove the choice if there is any to set the default value of dropdwon to blank.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So when you are creating a new item or editing an existing one, all the available options are displayed like this:

[image: Choices]

This is due to the way the column has been defined.  Go to List Settings>Columns>YourColumn>scroll down to `Display choices using:` then change the setting to `Drop-Down Menu`